# syntax error at or near "delete" on using "on delete cascade on delete update" in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to reference primary in one of the table as foreign key.
This is my table query for

Table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE public.group_master
(
    user_group Text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    type group_type
);
```

Table #2:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pravinyam_usermaster
(
    userid Text,
    password Text,
    role user_role,
    user_group Text,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_group) 
        REFERENCES public.group_master(user_group)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON DELETE UPDATE
);
```

I get this error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "delete"
> LINE 7: ...blic.group_master(user_group) ON DELETE CASCADE on delete upd...
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 246

How to resolve this error?

Comment: you can only specify `on delete` once.

Comment: which on delete should I write?

Comment: That’s up to you, you know if you want to cascade or update the referenced values. We don’t

Comment: Can't we write both ?

Comment: Whichever you want to keep but you can't delete the referenced rows **and** update them at the same time

Comment: Sure you can, but it’s not valid and will result in an error message. Did you check the manual?

Comment: Okay thanks I'll have a check

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Also there is no `UPDATE`  action to for either a `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `on delete` clauses - not only syntactically, but also logically. What would you expect the database to do when a parent record is deleted - delete the child record or update it?

Choose the right clause according to your application's logic, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.pravinyam_usermaster
(
    userid Text,
    password Text,
    role user_role,
    user_group Text,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_group) 
        REFERENCES public.group_master(user_group)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```